# What to do if my Background-img is not responsive on every device

Tags: ios, css, responsive-design, background, background-image

I am making my portfolio and i get stuck. I just made small view of it...how should it look. I started testing it on my PC it is OK...just how i want...than i started to test it on my iPad and the BACKGROUND-IMG was not fit but on my Sony Xperia mobile it was OK as on my PC. Can you please help me? Thank's 
---> link to testing website: http://marten.esy.es/ 
I hope there are some people which should help me with that :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things.  I would remove the fixed position from your background on slide 1.  Then change the property of background-size to cover.  This allows you to set a height for each of your media queries.  I would also suggest adding background-position: center; so the image always stays in the center relative to the div.

```
.slide1 {
background: url('mountainsmorning.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat;
color: #fff;
height: 400px;
margin: 0;
padding: 25% 0 30% 0;
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

as far as i could understand your question and after looking at the example i think the problem is with the covering the background to the whole view-port. If it's such then use the following style for your `.slide1` element.

```
.slide1 {
    background: url('mountainsmorning.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: #fff;
    /* height: 400px; */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25% 0 30% 0;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Note:** And don't use fixed height or width as you're developing for multiple screen sizes. Else's is fine.